# Username + [space] causes login.aspx redirect but Identity.IsAuthenticated is TRUE

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

I have a navigation control, shown only to authenticated users on the masterpage.  This is shown by testing

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true
```

I am using Forms Authentication with a Active Directory Membership and a login control.

If I log in using my username with a space on the end... 'username ' the page is 302'd to the returnurl, then sent straight back to login.aspx... but strangely when loading the login.aspx page the second time, IsAuthenticated remains true.

This means that our login page incorrectly shows the navigation...

So now I am redirected to the login screen even though IsAuthenticated is true, could anyone explain why this could be?

Obviously the space in the user name is wrong, but I want to ensure a user does not experience this.

This code works fine in every other scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a solution to the problem you are asking about, but may still solve it for you and should be done anyhow IMO:**

Why don't you apply a [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the username before processing it?

```
username = username.Trim();
```

This should remove any white space at the beginning and end and so the problematic situation should never happen.

Comment: I am using an ASP.NET login control, straight out of the box... I could maybe apply some javascript to trim it,

Comment: but users without javascript could still get this issue... I would prefer a server side solution...

Comment: I am using MVC so it is a bit different there, but is there no Server-Side code before the authentication you can change?

Comment: The login control takes care of User Identity side of things... I would like to know if there is a way of accessing this pre-processing the username & password

Comment: What control are you using? (May add that information to the question)

Comment: You were right... I found a method on the Login control called OnLoggingIn... I simply set the username to itself with a trim and it worked great.. Thanks        

protected void Login1_OnLoggingIn(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e) 
        {
            Login1.UserName = Login1.UserName.Trim();
        }

Answer (score 3):

You were right chrfin... I found a method on the Login control called OnLoggingIn... I simply set the username to itself with a trim and it worked great.. Thanks

```
protected void Login1_OnLoggingIn(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e) 
    {
        Login1.UserName = Login1.UserName.Trim();
    }
```